# The answer content is not shown

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app

To reproduce:

1. Visit [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16269635/4279)
2. Click the code block, to display it full screen
3. If you return to the answer; the content is gone (try landscape orientation if doesn't vanish)

Got:

[image: answer with content that is not shown]

Expected:

[image: answer with the content shown]

The current Stack Exchange 1.3.1 17/04/2015 version on iPhone 5s  iOS 8.3 is used.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on the latest version of the app.